# fetching comments from database along with the post URL in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Im writing a wordpress plugin, I need to export all the comments with their data, including the URL of Post that the comment was posted on

```
$args = array();
$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query( $args );
```

Im using this code now which returns only the comment related data, post_id, but I need URL of the post instead.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you have post_id, you have to query for the post to get its data...

Comment: you mean if I have 10,000 comments, I have to query for every comment to fetch the post details?

Comment: You may do a request by post ? So for each post, you retrieve comments from this post. Could it be a solution ? What do you want this for ?

Comment: this is for exporting, Im exporting all the comments along with their post URL

Comment: did you miss any link?

Comment: [here is the link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3849212/4786273). If you never wrote a SQL Query, we'll see together how to adapt it to your case...